# Adding Angular to an existing project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a project in ASP.NET, we are migrating to Angular, but until then we want to put Angular inside ASP.NET. Does anyone know how this Angular can be inserted into an existing project? As far as I worked with Angular it was necessary to give the build command

Comment: You should add the build directory of angular to your project and make sure your base url points to the folder

Comment: Just build the app somewhere and include <app-root> and the js scripts to any view you want..?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not something you add to an existing project as for example react or vue, angular is a framework which you use to a SPA from the ground up, you can't just add it to an existing project made using a different framework.